# Using the "New" OneDrive API to work with Albums

Tags: onedrive

I would like to work with Albums in the new SDK.

I can pull my album by ID using
https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drive/items/331C152AE0A57E96%21472628

But, I really need to be able to Search for a well known Album name to retrieve the ID first. This fails.
https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drive/items/root/view.search?q=MyAlbum

The Album that is returned when I retrieve metadata by ID does not have a ParentReference. So, I may be searching in completely the wrong path.

In the old SDK you could use /me/albums. In the new one I just don't know where to look... Albums aren't a special folder.

Anyone able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: The new SDK doesn't really have a concept of albums, just folders. That said, searching for a name should return the relevant items. Is your issue that search isn't returning the item at all or that it's not returning ParentReference?

Answer (score 1):

probably too late for you, but I have just found a solution, so I share it for a future reference:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/<user-id>!0:/SkyDriveCache/Albums:
```

It is of course undocumented.

`<user-id>` is OneDrive user's ID, which you can obtain e.g. by `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me`

Folder `<user-id>!0` seems to be some "super-root" folder, however you cannot access its `/children`. `:/SkyDriveCache/Albums:` returns the OneDrive Albums folder. Its `/children` return your albums.

Comment: Thanks a million! Have you figured out also a path for Tags or Places?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try using https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drive/items/root/children which will get all of the folders located in the root drive.  From there, you should be able to check the folders to see if they have children as well by using GET /drive/items/{id}/children or GET /drive/root:/{path}:/children.  I hope that helps.

Toan

Answer (score 0):

The OneDrive API does not support Album as of yet, this is one of the reasons that you are having an impossibly hard time finding those details.  You can expect any feature that we have on our website other applications to be available on this API over time as build it up.

If you think we are missing any other feature on this API I'd highly recommend using our [UserVoice](http://onedrive.uservoice.com/forums/262982-onedrive/category/89523-developer) to mention what you what.